# c# csvfile to array

Tags: c#, csv, toarray

I had a **.csv** file with many lines and 3 columns (separated by ';') with numbers, which I convert to `double array[][]`
Now I've added to more columns of numbers and get an error:

> FormatException -> Input string was not in a correct format

I can't find whats wrong because files are identical (but with 2 more columns)
My code:

```
OpenFileDialog fD = new OpenFileDialog();
fD.Title = "select";
fD.Filter = "csv files|*.csv";
fD.InitialDirectory = @"path here";
if (fD.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    MessageBox.Show(fD.FileName.ToString());

double[][] termom = File.ReadLines(fD.FileName)
    .Select(l => l.Split(';')
        .Select(n => double.Parse(n))
        .ToArray())
    .ToArray();
```

Edit
Thanks for help with edit - not very used to commands here. Hope i added file right
[original](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AlAC4AoN2hyJhX2tmvDJ_92OeL9L)
[improved](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AlAC4AoN2hyJhX7VnWh64AIQRKpG)

Comment: Check your input data. Something cannot be parsed to a double

Comment: It's impossible to help without seeing the original file and the new file.

Comment: You may have blank rows or null data (no numbers between the semicolons) which give the exception.  It is not a good idea to attempt to read the entire file with one line of code.  Write code that is more robust.

Comment: Can you provide us a sample of your .csv file?

Comment: @Tim Schmelter
added both files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your file `res1.csv` (providing that it should contain `double` values only) has some *syntax errors*, e.g.

> 1881081,9;6,315177;352,499964;**01,06,1974**;350,645

What is the meaning of `01,06,1974`? Shall we *ignore* commas (treat them as, say, some kind of *thousands separator*)? Or is it a *date* (`1 June 1974`)? Yet another possibility is that `,` is a *deriver*, so we have *three* separate values: `1`, `6` and `1974`

In case you want to *ignore commas* (and thus **01,06,1974** will be **1061974.0**), just specify `InvariantCulture` while parsing:

```
double[][] termom = File.ReadLines(fD.FileName)
  .Select(l => l.Split(';')
    .Select(n => double.Parse(n, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
    .ToArray())
  .ToArray();
```

If you want to treat `,` as a deriver (and thus **01,06,1974** will be **[1.0, 6.0, 1974.0]**)

```
double[][] termom = File.ReadLines(fD.FileName)
  .Select(l => l.Split(';', ',') // ',' is a deriver as well as ';'
    .Select(n => double.Parse(n, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
    .ToArray())
  .ToArray();
```

Comment: dang it
converted some parts in excell first - seems like 5 elements were treated as date\time
thx it works now